# Sharepoint list - Infopath form set default attachment documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, attachments, sharepoint-list

I have a Sharepoint list and need to add 2 documents as a default attachment to each user-created form on creation.
The form is made with InfoPath 2013. I have an attachment field and it works fine, but I dont know how to achieve a default where - on form creation in the list there are already 2 documents attached.

Is that possible in any way?

Comment: Could you not just upload the two files to a document library and reference them in your InfoPath form?

Comment: No thats not an option unluckily. They need to be hard attached to the form

Comment: Are you using SharePoint on-premises?

Comment: @CallumCrowley Yes we do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, we cannot set a default value for the list item attachment. Adding a column holding the link to the documents is a doable workaround.

And if that does not satisfy you, you may try to embed the document inside the list item new, display or edit form depending on your final goal.

Comment: How do I the second option you mentioned

Comment: @Xnolbay, try this blog:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/embed-word-documents-contentson-a-sharepoint-page-in-office/